# Google AMP Multiple amp-link-rewriter configs

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I have a use case for adding multiple redirection rules in a Google AMP page.
I tried the following for doing this:

**Try 1: Adding another [amp-link-rewriter](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-link-rewriter/) tag in the html, with second config**

```
<amp-link-rewriter layout="nodisplay">
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "output": "https://stackoverflow.com/?b=c&d=f",
                "attribute": { "href": ".*google.*" },
            }
        </script>
</amp-link-rewriter>
<amp-link-rewriter layout="nodisplay">
        <script type="application/json">
            {
                "output": "https://def.com/?x=y&d=f",
                "attribute": { "href": ".*facebook.*" },
            }
        </script>
</amp-link-rewriter>
```

This works for the page but gives the following error while AMP page validaton

"The tag 'amp-link-rewriter' appears more than once in the document."

**Try 2: Tried using [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/) extension for rewriting links.**

AMP allows DOM modification only if

1. The html enclosed in the amp-script tag has fixed-size containers.
   This option is very limited, as it breaks the appearance of the page
2. It allows modifying DOM on user action for variable-size containers
   I tried adding following code to the anchor tag in html:

HTML code

```html
<amp-script src="/js/amptry.js">
    <a href="https://www.google.com>Google</a><br>
</amp-script>
```

amptry.js

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a').forEach((link, idx) => {
    if (link.href) {
        link.addEventListener('click', () => {
            try {
                const url = new URL(link.href);
                const regex = /.*google./;
                if (url.hostname.match(regex)) {
                    link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/?b=c&d=f';
                }
            } catch(err) {console.log(err.message)}
        })
    }
});
```

This modifies the anchor tag but **after** the click has happened. Basically the page opened is still google.com on first click and then gets changed to stackoverflow.com on subsequent clicks.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: For "Try 1" what happens if you put the two scripts in a single controller? When you define IDs, and then hydrate the anchor element with JSON values for an ID, each anchor should expand correctly. I'll leave it to you to test that approach and update your question. Be sure to show how you format `<a>`

Comment: amp complaints about two scripts when only one is expected. "Uncaught (in promise) Resource: failed to build: amp-link-rewriter#1: %s: %s amp-link-rewriter: Found 2 <script> children. Expected 1. _reported_"

Comment: Just to be clear, your comment is a different test. You are not just clarifying "Try 1".

Comment: yes, thats correct. The error in comment is when there are two srcipt tags are in one amp-link-rewriter tag.

Comment: sounds like a bug. i'll test this on my side using both test cases (multiple controllers; multiple scripts per controller). if a bug, the next step is to open an issue on github-amp-dev. google usually reacts quickly to these issues.

Comment: Have asked google. let's see what they say.

Comment: ok, i had opened a feature request also - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/34607, thought this was intended behaviour.

Comment: Good. Google-AMP is checking with the responsible developer. Should hear back soon.

Comment: @JayGray Any updates on this?

Comment: Still waiting; will re-ping google.